# How make iOS UIActivityViewController show "Open in Google Earth" for local KML file?

Tags: ios, pdf, kml

**Using iOS Mail app:**

1. I can select a KML email attachment in the iOS mail app.
2. When the AirDrop page appears, **Open in Google Earth** is one of the choices.

How can I make my app work the same as iOS mail app?

When I use UIActivityViewController and create a NSURL to the local KML file, the AirDrop page appears displaying Mail, Facebook, Gmail, but **NOT** "Open in Google Earth" ?

```
NSURL* urlToLocalKmlFile=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:localKmlFilePath];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[urlToLocalKmlFile];
activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare
applicationActivities:nil];
```

How does iOS Mail share a KML file attachment with Goggle Earth or a PDF file attachment with Adobe Acrobat?

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions,
-Ed

[image: iOS Mail shows Open in Google Earth]

Comment: You might want a UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: localKmlFilePath: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E06D33D8-AA84-4CCC-B861-93EC49203324/Documents/tmp/JOB-0001/JOB-0001.kml
urlToLocalKmlFile: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E06D33D8-AA84-4CCC-B861-93EC49203324/Documents/tmp/JOB-0001/JOB-0001.kml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the documentation of [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/) by Apple.

I've tried it now and the *Open in GoogleEarth* option appears when you use that controller. For example to present it from a button (called `button`) for a path called `url` in a view controller:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
[interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you Peter and rmaddy. UIDocumentInteractionController provided the solution I wanted and matches the screenshot.